# Назначение двойного амперсанда в функции вывода

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Эта функция выводит true если в строке встречается одинаковое количество 'X' и 'O'. Непонятно как работает эта строка `return ( x && x.length) === (o && o.length)` какую роль выполняет двойной амперсанд ?

```
function XO(str) {
  let x = str.match(/x/gi);
  let o = str.match(/o/gi);
  return ( x && x.length) === (o && o.length);

}
console.log( XO('xxOo'));
```

Comment: То, что вы называете "двойным амперсандом", во многих языках программирования называется [логическим оператором "И"](https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops#i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `&&` возвращает второй операнд, если оба операнда соответствуют значению `true`, или первый встретившийся операнд с значением `false`.

```js
console.log(10 && 23);
console.log(10 && 0);
console.log(0 && 10);
console.log(false && 0);
```

Другими словами, он возвращает последний вычисленный операнд.